# Text autoscroll in c pebble sdk 2.0

Tags: c, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I'm trying to autoscroll text in screen.(Like html horizontal marquee)I tried
http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/65998-how-scroll-your-text.html
that but it isnt working.
How can i do that with pebble sdk 2.0?
Pebble Codes:

```
#include <pebble.h>

static Window *window;
static TextLayer *text_layer;

static void select_click_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context) {
  text_layer_set_text(text_layer, "Select");
}

static void up_click_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context) {
  text_layer_set_text(text_layer, "Up");
}

static void down_click_handler(ClickRecognizerRef recognizer, void *context) {
  text_layer_set_text(text_layer, "Down");
}

static void click_config_provider(void *context) {
  window_single_click_subscribe(BUTTON_ID_SELECT, select_click_handler);
  window_single_click_subscribe(BUTTON_ID_UP, up_click_handler);
  window_single_click_subscribe(BUTTON_ID_DOWN, down_click_handler);
}

static void window_load(Window *window) {
  Layer *window_layer = window_get_root_layer(window);
  GRect bounds = layer_get_bounds(window_layer);

  text_layer = text_layer_create((GRect) { .origin = { 0, 72 }, .size = { bounds.size.w, 20 } });
  text_layer_set_text(text_layer, "Press a button");
  text_layer_set_text_alignment(text_layer, GTextAlignmentCenter);
  layer_add_child(window_layer, text_layer_get_layer(text_layer));
}

static void window_unload(Window *window) {
  text_layer_destroy(text_layer);
}

static void init(void) {
  window = window_create();
  window_set_click_config_provider(window, click_config_provider);
  window_set_window_handlers(window, (WindowHandlers) {
    .load = window_load,
    .unload = window_unload,
  });
  const bool animated = true;
  window_stack_push(window, animated);
 text_layer = text_layer_create(GRect(0, 0, 144, 168));
text_layer_set_background_color(text_layer, GColorClear);
text_layer_set_text_color(text_layer, GColorBlack);
layer_add_child(window_get_root_layer(window), (Layer*) text_layer);
  text_layer_set_text(text_layer, "Aasasfnything you want, as long as it is in quotes!");

}

static void deinit(void) {
    text_layer_destroy(text_layer);
  window_destroy(window);
}

int main(void) {
  init();

  APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "Done initializing, pushed window: %p", window);

  app_event_loop();
  deinit();
}
```

Online IDE for Pebble cloudpebble.net
Thank You

Comment: Please give some more context or supply some code so that people can understand your question better.

Comment: Code and more information added.

Comment: Thank you for improving your question.